# Cant add foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, primary-key

When I try to migrate I get an error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed", but I cant see why

1st table

```
    Schema::create('uciteles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('admin');
        $table->string('predmet');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

2nd table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think here first you create uciteles table then users table.
so here change that format.first create users table & then uciteles table.

change the time of created table in migration like this 2019_09_27_000000_create_users_table.php  change date & month then users table create first & secondly the uciteles table or disble foreign key check & enable it

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
Schema::create('uciteles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('admin');
        $table->string('predmet');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting error that is saying "Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value" I tried to do ->nullable() but that doesnt worked.

Comment: make it nullable() & php artisan migrate:refresh

Answer (score 0):

The type of the column must be the same as in the foreign key reference and you need to create the column yourself.

Here are the explanations to your question : [Creating Foreign Key in Laravel Migrations](https://coderwall.com/p/o73fbq/creating-foreign-key-in-laravel-migrations)

Comment: I tried to change 'id' to "ncrements and 'user_id' to integer, but still getting the same error.